# I want the elements in my array to be clickable so that they get redirected to other html views

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angular, i am developing a shopping cart where the user should be able to filter the products and click on a product to gets details about them, i am able to create elements in array and filter them using ng-repeat but how can i make that elements to be links? here is my code for better understanding.

```
<h2>Welcome To Angular Store...</h2>   
<ul><li ng-repeat="p in products">{{p.name}</li> </ul>  app.controller('storecontroller', function($scope){$scope.products = [
    {name:'iphone'},
    {name:'oneplue'},
    {name:'moto'}]});
```

Comment: Try using `ng-click` directive

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngHref to create safe links to content in your table, take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy : 'Country'|filter:search">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td><a ng-href="{linkhere}">{{ x.Country }}</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("customers.php")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>
```

Comment: but i want to apply filter to the elements,so i have to put them in a array and then display them using ng-repeat ,so in a array how to make these elements as links?

Comment: i edited the answer, added an example with a table with links.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function inside the controller which returns reference to the scope
 below are the example code for your reference, full working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEjch2sP230tQ50c9bee?p=preview)

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.search = {};
    $scope.search.vehicles = "Car";

      $scope.allvehicles =  [
        {"vehicles":"car"}, 
        {"vehicles":"bus"},        
    ];

  $scope.options=[{"vehicles":"Car","type":"Hatchback"},
  {"vehicles":"Car","type":"Sedan"},
  {"vehicles":"Car","type":"SUV"},
  {"vehicles":"Car","type":"MUV"},
  {"vehicles":"bus","type":"Multiaxel"},
    {"vehicles":"bus","type":"SemiSleeper"},
      {"vehicles":"bus","type":"Deluxe"},
        {"vehicles":"bus","type":"Sleeper"}]


      $scope.getAllVehicles = function() {
         return $scope;   
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>Vehicles Available </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="vehiclez in allvehicles">
              <a href="#" ng-click="getAllVehicles().search.vehicles = vehiclez.vehicles;">
                {{ vehiclez.vehicles }}
            </a>
    </div>
    <h4>Vehicles types </h4>
    <div ng-repeat="typez in options | filter:search">
      {{typez.type}}
    </div>

  </body>
```